# Export STEP file using Blender

Tags: export

I am creating STL file using blender api and it is working fine. Now I have requirement of creating STEP file instead of STL file. Do blender support STEP format. Can we export STEP file using blender. I did R&D but didn't find any satisfactory answer.

During R&D I came to know stepper addon for blender. Using this Adon we can import STEP file in blender but still not found anything for exporting STEP file using Blender.

Comment: STEP is a CAD format, Blender is not a CAD program and cannot deal with solid based geometry